# Warning while using file_get_contents for google api

Tags: php, google-maps

I am using this code for finding the lat lon of a location

```
$api='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=United States Neversink&sensor=false';

$result = file_get_contents($api);

$data = json_decode($result);
```

But it give the warning Warning: file_get_contents(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=United States Neversink&sensor=false) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in C:\wamp\www\new_yellowpages\modules\mod_yellowpages_item_map\helper.php on line 139

if anyone know about this problem help me please.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use curl instead of `file_get_contents`:

```
$address = "India+Panchkula";
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=India";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response_a = json_decode($response);
echo $lat = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
echo "<br />";
echo $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

Answer (score 15):

Use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode the address part. (The problem is the space in the address.)

```
$address = urlencode("United States Neversink");
$api='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false';

$result = file_get_contents($api);
```

Comment: The combination of both answers (Abid & xdazz ) helped me!

Answer (score 1):

Use urlenocde function to encode your address like google map standard and change Http to https. Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try change HTTP to HTTPS and replace ' ' to '+'

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=United+States+Neversink&sensor=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the issue is related to OpenSSL on Ubuntu 22.4

I have just updated my packages on ubuntu server and It works correctly,

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Answer (score -2):

Use curl_init() instead of file_get_contents():

```
$address = "India+Panchkula";
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=India";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$response_a = json_decode($response);
echo $lat = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
echo "<br />";
echo $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```