# php xml Google Geocoding Error

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, google-geocoder

if i understand the google error OVER_QUERY_LIMIT right, than it comes because of too many ip-requests.
BUT if I go to the browser and load the following link:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Paris&sensor=true

I can see the xml!

So why is that?

Do I have a problem in my code?

Here it is:

```
    $the_map = htmlspecialchars($_POST['map'], ENT_QUOTES);

    error_reporting(0);
    $map_query = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address='.rawurlencode($the_map).'&sensor=false');
    error_reporting(1);

    if ($map_query){
        $geo_code = simplexml_load_string(utf8_encode($map_query));

        if ($geo_code){
            $map_lat = $geo_code->xpath("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat");
            $map_lng = $geo_code->xpath("/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng");
            $map_lat = $map_lat[0][0];
            $map_lng = $map_lng[0][0];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **curl** instead of **file_get_contents**:

```
$address = "India+Panchkula";
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=India";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response_a = json_decode($response);
echo $lat = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
echo "<br />";
echo $long = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

**Or See the below URL**

[Warning while using file_get_contents for google api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293848/warning-while-using-file-get-contents-for-google-api/12294015#12294015)

Comment: ok. after a few days i have the same problem with "curl". I get this "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" Error. But it makes no sense, i don't have that many requests to google. max 10 per day. so what .. how can i solve the problem?