# PHP - Google Maps API search return ZERO_RESULTS but Navigator show it

Tags: php, google-maps, curl, google-maps-api-3

i have a bit problem,

i need to get the coordinates of a place from the name of the road (what i provide), i try to do it with `file_get_contents` & `json_decode`, but some of them don't work (return a stdClass with **ZERO_RESULTS**) !

if i copy paste the url (exaclty the same) in the browser, it send me the right data, *doesn't know why*.

if i try with a another road name, it works.

obviously i already tried to clear the cache, but no result, change the navigator doesn't work too, tried on multiple servers too, but still no results, tried to do it with CURL ([as provided as an answer in a post relating the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293848/warning-while-using-file-get-contents-for-google-api)), but still, no result.

i'm quite lost, i hope you can help me with this.

here the code.

*The data provided is from **France** road names, you can add "France " in the $a if you want to see it*

**DATA**

```
// Not Working
$a = "17 bis Les Chaises";
$b = "77510";

// Working
$a = "2 rue Jean Moulin";
$b = "70300";
```

**Links Generated**

```
// Not Working
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=17+bis+Les+Chaises+77510

// Working
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2+rue+Jean+Moulin+70300
```

**CURL**

```
$url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".str_replace(" ","+",$a)."+".$b;
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$response_a = json_decode($response);

print_r($response_a);
```

**file_get_contents**

```
$j = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".str_replace(" ","+",$a)."+".$b),true);

print_r("https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".str_replace(" ","+",$a)."+".$b);echo "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
print_r($j["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"].",".$j["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]);

var_dump(file_get_contents("https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".str_replace(" ","+",$a)."+".$b));
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that if you add +France to the your search criteria, your non-working request not works.

```
// Not Working
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=17+bis+Les+Chaises+77510 

// Working
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=17+bis+Les+Chaises+77510+France
```

Comment: Work in php with the `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Looks like working, doesn't know why.
Did you have an idea why did i have to add "+France" for working?

Comment: The address without a search descriptor of France seemed maybe too ambiguous for Google to pinpoint. I would at least attempt to add a country code if you can. Plus, the ZIP might be mistaken for US.

Comment: Okay, that seems to be usefull to remind. 
Anyway, thanks a lot for your help ;D