# Google maps API key causing issue with file_get_contents() in php

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a pho script that takes an address and returns the lat/lon.  Works fine until I put the google api key at the end of the url. I tested the url in the browser and it works fine there.

This works fine:

```
$geo = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($address).'&sensor=false');
```

This causes an error:

```
$geo = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($address).'+&sensor=false+CA&key=[MyAPIKeyHere]');
```

It causes the error:  failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request

I've seen consulted similar posts such as, 
 [Warning while using file_get_contents for google api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12293848/warning-while-using-file-get-contents-for-google-api) , but they weren't much help.

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php

// Address
$address = '1451 Broadway New York, NY 10036';

// Address from command line
// $address = readline("Enter an address: ");
// $address = str_replace(' ','+',$address);

// Get JSON results from this request
// This url works
$geo = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($address).'&sensor=false');

// This url creates an error
//$geo = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.urlencode($address).'+&sensor=false+CA&key=[MyAPIKeyHere]');

// Convert the JSON to an array
$geo = json_decode($geo, true);

if ($geo['status'] == 'OK') {
  // Get Lat & Long
  $latitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
  $longitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
}

// $address = str_replace('+',' ',$address);
echo "The address ". $address. " has the following coordinates:\n" ;
echo "Lat: ". $latitude. " Lon: ". $longitude. "\n";

?>
```

Comment: Why `&sensor=false+CA` (BTW `sensor` is no longer required)

Comment: The url doesn't work with the API key if sensor isn't there.

Comment: Try to replace + with its conresponding url encode, which is %2B

Answer (score 0):

Try using this API. It worked for me.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$address.'&key=YOUR_API_KEY'
```